# How to search two columns in the same input using Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have a function for search in a single column

Here is:

```
public function resultados_asesores(Request $request){
  $busqueda = $request->asesor;
  $asesores = strtoupper($busqueda);
  $perimetro = DB::table('tbl_perimetros as a')
    ->select('a.id','a.rif','a.cod_cliente','a.razon_social','a.holdings_id')
    ->leftjoin('tbl_holdings as b','b.id','=','a.holdings_id')
    ->leftjoin('tbl_equipo_postventaatcs as c','c.id','=','a.postventaatc_id')
    ->leftjoin('users as e','e.id','=','c.asesor_id')
    ->select(array('a.id','b.hrif','b.hrazon_social','a.rif','a.razon_social','a.estatus'))
    ->where('e.name','like', '%' . $asesores . '%')
    ->orWhere('e.apellido', 'like', '%' . $asesores . '%')
    ->orWhere('e.idop', 'like', '%' . $asesores . '%')
    ->get();

  if($perimetro->count()) {

    return view('Busqueda.resultados_busquedag',compact('perimetro','busqueda'));
  }

      return view('Busqueda.index');
}
```

I have a problem because I would like to be able to search name and apellido at the same time in the same search... but in this way I can only search name or apellido... if I write in the search both (name and apellido) it returns me and error.. How could I search the two columns at the same time?

this is my input

```
<form id="asesor" class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('resultados_asesores')}}" method="post">
@csrf
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-md-6 col-form-label" for="asesor"></label>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <input form="asesor" maxlength="100" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="asesor" type="text" name="asesor" placeholder="Introduzca el nombre, apellido o IDOP del asesor a buscar">
    <br>
    <div class="pull-right">
    <button form="asesor" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" type="submit">
      Buscar</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what's your error?

Comment: I can't search name and apellido at the same time

Comment: well is there any error message?

Comment: no...  I got  return view('Busqueda.index'); if I search the two columns

Comment: it exists a method to search e.name and e.apellido in the same input?

Answer (score 0):

Write your query like this

```
$perimetro = DB::table('tbl_perimetros as a')
        ->select('a.id', 'a.rif', 'a.cod_cliente', 'a.razon_social', 'a.holdings_id')
        ->leftjoin('tbl_holdings as b', 'b.id', '=', 'a.holdings_id')
        ->leftjoin('tbl_equipo_postventaatcs as c', 'c.id', '=', 'a.postventaatc_id')
        ->leftjoin('users as e', 'e.id', '=', 'c.asesor_id')
        ->select(['a.id', 'b.hrif', 'b.hrazon_social', 'a.rif', 'a.razon_social', 'a.estatus'])
        ->where('e.name', 'like', '%'.$asesores.'%')
        ->where('e.apellido', 'like', '%'.$asesores.'%')
        ->orWhere('e.idop', 'like', '%'.$asesores.'%')
        ->get();
```

Comment: I obtained this SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `a`.`id`, `b`.`hrif`, `b`.`hrazon_social`, `a`.`rif`, `a`.`razon_social`, `a`.`estatus` from `tbl_perimetros` as `a` left join `tbl_holdings` as `b` on `b`.`id` = `a`.`holdings_id` left join `tbl_equipo_postventaatcs` as `c` on `c`.`id` = `a`.`postventaatc_id` left join `users` as `e` on `e`.`id` = `c`.`asesor_id` where (`0` = e.name and `1` = like and `2` = %YORVIS% and `3` = e.apellido and `4` = like and `5` = %YORVIS%) or `e`.`idop` like

Comment: In this way I got the else return view('Busqueda.index');

Comment: so you don't have items in your db with your search query, because this code will search in both of name and apellido

Comment: Yes I have... I'm searching just a name and last name that I have in my db... in my columns name and apellido